# Problema con instrucción fetch()

Tags: javascript, response, fetch

Porque no muestra nada al ejecutar el siguiente código?

```
created(){
     fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/74l63")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                   this.products = json.products
                   console.log(this.products)
            })
         }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.  La verdad sigo con el mismo problema. 
 Estou utilizando Vue JS.  El código completo es el siguiente: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Amcoy6b-4z0zgYMLCRiQohlljzyBrg

Comment: El código funciona correctamente, ¿Está seguro que importa correctamente VueJs? intente cambiar por el [CDN](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.min.js) directamente

Comment: OK, ya me funcioné, tenía el error al importar el Vue.js.  Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Tu codigo funciona si agregas la palabra `function`

```js
function created(){
     fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/74l63")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(json => {
                   this.products = json.products
                   console.log(this.products)
            })
         }
created();
```